# Efficiently Query Solr 9 for Similarity Score with Filter Queries

Tags: vector, solr, knn, information-retrieval

I'm using Solr 9 for optimal query-document similarity calculations. I have a use-case where I have to query for specific field values first, and then compute document similarities on all of the documents that are found.

My problem is as follows:
If each document has a field "embedding" and "id", I want to only retrieve documents with id=1,2,3, and given a query embedding, return the similarity score of each document with the query embedding.

**Option 1**: Query for the id's using `fq`, and the `q` field using `knn`. Not all documents that I want will be returned because of the limitation below.

The main issue with this is documented [here](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/dense-vector-search.html#usage-as-re-ranking-query):

```
When using knn in re-ranking pay attention to the topK parameter.
The second pass score(deriving from knn) is calculated only if the document d from the first pass is within the k-nearest neighbors(in the whole index) of the target vector to search.
This means the second pass knn is executed on the whole index anyway, which is a current limitation.
```

**Option 2**: Query for the id's using `fq`, get the `embedding` in the field list, and compute the similarities in memory. The issue with that is the network latency, since the size of the response from Solr is large when retrieving the embeddings.

That leaves the following two questions:

1. When will the limitation in the document above be solved, if at all?
2. Is there a way to compress the response from Solr such that I can retrieve the response faster?

Thanks!

Comment: Generally the `csv` output format is by far the quickest - you probably also want to look into using the `/export` endpoint if you're going to calculate items yourself. Writing a custom similarity class is also an option if you haven't looked into it. Using a streaming expression and possibly adding your own function there is also an option if you can't use the existing `knnSearch`: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/machine-learning.html#knnsearch (or knn linked above): https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/machine-learning.html#k-nearest-neighbor-knn

Comment: In order to use the `/export` endpoint, the desired fields need to have `docValues=true`. DenseVectorFields don't support that.

Answer (score 0):

you can try **vectorSimilarity Function** ,which returns the similarity between two Knn vectors in an n-dimensional space.
refer to [solr 9.4 vectorSimilarity Function](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/function-queries.html#vectorsimilarity-function)